# How to return errors from PYODBC

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm making a connection to `SQL Server` to execute a stored procedure.  What is the correct way to 'poll' the server to determine whether the stored procedure finished running successfully or returned an error if the SP takes longer than 60 seconds / 3600 seconds, etc?

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=ServerName; PORT=1433;DATABASE=dbname;UID=%s;PWD=%s'  % (username, password))
cnxn.execute("EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'TestSP'")
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x0000000002D6DDB0>
```

How can I determine the status of the SP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider wrapping the `execute` in a try/except to catch exceptions (which [encompass errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)). If no error is raised, `execute` is assumed to run correctly. Also, use the [timeout variable](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Connection.wiki) (in seconds) as the database should raise `OperationError` if timeout occurs.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=ServerName; PORT=1433; \
                       DATABASE=dbname;UID={0};PWD={1}'.format(username, password))

cnxn.timeout = 60    
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
try:
    cnxn.execute("EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'TestSP'")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've skipped making a cursor, so you need to do that, then fetch the results. Try this:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=ServerName; PORT=1433;DATABASE=dbname;UID=%s;PWD=%s'  % (username, password))

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'TestSP'")

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    # Do stuff
    print(row)
```